# Conditional required property in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to define a conditionally required property that satisfies the following situation.

```
const Component = (props: Props) => {
  return <>...</>;
};

...

{/* wants to NOT occurs errors */}
<Component hasPet petName="puppy" friendNames={['John', 'Jane']} />
<Component hasPet={false} friendNames={['John', 'Jane']} />
<Component friendNames={['John', 'Jane']} />

{/* wants to occurs errors */}
<Component hasPet friendNames={['John', 'Jane']} />
<Component hasPet={false} petName="puppy" friendNames={['John', 'Jane']} />
<Component petName="puppy" friendNames={['John', 'Jane']} />
```

Of course, I realize that this could be solved if we defined `Props` like below.

```
type Props = {
  friendNames: string[];
} & (
  | {
      hasPet: true;
      petName: string;
    }
  | {
      hasPet?: false;
      petName?: undefined;
    }
);
```

However, there is a limitation: I can't use extends with `Props` defined like above.

```
// ts(2312) error:
// An interface can only extend an object type or
// intersection of object types with statically known members.

interface ExtendedProps extends Props { }
```

So I tried it like below, but it doesn't work as desired.

```
interface Props<T extends boolean> {
  hasPet?: T;
  petName: T extends true ? string : never;
  friendNames: string[];
}
```

Is there any way to declare `Props` that satisfies below conditions and is extensible?

```
const Component = (props: Props) => {
  return <>...</>;
};

...

{/* wants to NOT occurs errors */}
<Component hasPet petName="puppy" friendNames={['John', 'Jane']} />
<Component hasPet={false} friendNames={['John', 'Jane']} />
<Component friendNames={['John', 'Jane']} />

{/* wants to occurs errors */}
<Component hasPet friendNames={['John', 'Jane']} />
<Component hasPet={false} petName="puppy" friendNames={['John', 'Jane']} />
<Component petName="puppy" friendNames={['John', 'Jane']} />
```

Comment: Why do you need the `ExtendedProps` interface, couldn't you just use the `Props` type?

Comment: `type ExtendedProps = Props & WhateverElse;`